# How to trigger a selection using onchange using unobtrusive jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Assume I have a vanilla form containing a selection list and a submit button:

```
<%= form_for(@report :url => report_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:sort_by, options_for_select(Report.SORT_OPTIONS, @report.sort_by)) %>
  <%= f.submit 'sort' %>
<% end %>
```

Works fine, except that the user has to first make a selection and then click 'sort'.  What I'd really like is to have the action triggered when the user makes a selection and to ditch the 'sort' button altogether.  This feels like a perfect use case for unobtrusive jQuery.

So [based on responses from @Dennis and @ethan below], before this `form_for` I added:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag(:defaults) %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var $select = $('#report_sort_by'),
      $form = $select.closest('form');
  // $('[type="submit"]', $form).attr('type', 'hidden'); // gives error
  $('[type="submit"]', $form).hide();                    // works
  $select.change(function() { $form.submit(); });
});
</script>
```

So is it considered right to plunk javascript right into the .html.erb file?  Or is it better to put this in a separate .js file, and if so, what are the conventions for paramaterizing and naming the .js file?

For a few reputation points, can someone show me and all the other tyros how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails will stringify the object & property you're using, so the select menu would have `id="report_sort_by"`. Which means you could use:

```
var $select = $('#report_sort_by'),
    $form = $select.closest('form');

// preserve the button's name/value attributes, if Rails has assigned them
$('[type="submit"]', $form).hide();

$select.change(function() {
  $form.submit();
});
```

If you want to include this code in a robust, unobtrusive way, you could make a file called maybe MyProject.Report.js and put this code in it:

```
if (!MyProject) var MyProject = {};

MyProject.Report = {
  init: function() {
    var $select = $('#report_sort_by'),
        $form = $select.closest('form');

    // preserve the button's name/value attributes, if Rails has assigned them
    $('[type="submit"]', $form).hide();

    $select.change(function() {
      $form.submit();
    });
  }
}
```

Then in your .erb file (at the bottom, after the form) you could add `<script type="text/javascript">MyProject.Report.init();</script>` and then, of course, add the `javascript_include_tag` to include the JS file itself.

There's a bunch of different ways you could do your namespacing & encapsulation. The `MyProject.Report` object that I describe above has the chief advantage of being incredibly straightforward. As your code grows, you just add new functionality inside the `MyProject.Report` object like:

```
MyProject.Report = {
  init: function(options) {
    // some event handlers, maybe
    this.complication(null, null, options.data);
    this.reusable(options.bgcolor);
  },

  complication: function(a, b, c) {
    // stuff that's tough to look at
    this.reusable(b);
  },

  reusable: function(q) {
    // code that's used multiple places
  }
}
```

And then you basically hack away at that until you're knowledgeable enough to decide whether you need a framework like backbone.js for a given project :)

Comment: cool beans - I can see the generated #report_sort_by tag and all.  But to show the depths of my ignorance: Do you put that .js code in public/javascripts/application.js, and then put `<%= javascript_include_tag("/javascripts/application.js") %>` in the view where you want it?  Or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: By the way, the line `$('[type="submit"]', $form).attr('type', 'hidden');` give me an error: `Uncaught type property can't be changed`, though it worked when I changed that to a simple hide, as in `$('[type="submit"]', $form).hide()`.  See edits to original post for more info...

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the error. I changed that in my answer. Where you put the code is mostly philosophical, and pretty academic for a code snippet this small. Your solution of putting it in application.js is fine (better than putting it into the .erb or .rhtml file, at least for JS code of any real size) although I might argue that application.js should really only have code that is global, and that since this code targets a specific ID for a select menu that will probably only exist on a single page, then it doesn't tehnically belong there.

Comment: If you want to go a little bit overboard and set up a framework with simple namespacing that you can add to later, you could make a file called, like, Report.js or YourProjectAcronym.Report.js and put the code in it. I'm adding this idea to my answer above because I can't seem to do properly-indented code in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the updates!  So, If I *really* wanted to do this right, I'd create `public/javascripts/autotrigger_selection.js` and modify the js code to look for a <div class="autotrigger">...</div> wrapping the entire form.  Then I would use `javascript_include_tag` to load that file in any file where I wanted to create this behavior.  Agreed?

Comment: Yeah! Make your code generic/re-usable whenever you can, but... write it once the quick way and then wait and see whether you ever actually *need* it again before you spend a bunch of time abstracting it :) I think I would suggest adding `class="autosubmit"` to the select menu itself, then using the "start from the menu, then trigger `submit` on the parent form" approach taken by the original code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Ruby-on-Rails, so you may have to change the selectors but the general idea is:

```
$("#formId input[type='submit']").hide(); //Make the submit button invisible

$("#formId select.selectClass").change( function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit(); //Trigger the submit event on the parent form.
});
```

---

It looks like you can set the id like this:

```
:html => {:id => 'formId', :method => :put }
```

Comment: Points for the straightforward jQuery code -- it makes sense.  I'm trying to stitch together all the pieces, i.e. does RoR generate a well-defined id or class for the form that I can use in my jQuery code, should I use the RoR :remote option, etc.  If nobody comes forward with the complete answer within a couple of days, I'll give you the checkmark as well.  Thanks!